# automatically update web.config in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config

I need to automatically update the web.config file with a new IP address.

To put it in very simple terms as I am very new to C# and ASP.NET. I need to accept an IP address that a user puts into a form, validate it and then automatically add it to the web.config.

Unfortunately I cannot even seem to get started with it so I have no existing code except the default web.config file that has automatically been generated by Visual Studio 2010.

So I just found this: just an example

`<appSettings> 
        <add key="sqlConn" value="Server=myPc;Database=Northwind" /> 
        <add key="smtpServer" value="smtp.mydomain.com" /> 
    </appSettings>`

Would this do the trick??

Please let me know if this is possible and how I go about doing it. Or at least if I'm in the right track

So the user puts in the IP which gets accepted in a class that I'll make and then passed to this section in the web.config.

I've also now found this. It's quite a bit of code so just posting the link.
http://andersnordby.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/creating-a-custom-section-in-web-config/

I know I'm being a real noob now but just need a nudge in the right direction

Comment: web.config is just xml.

Comment: IMHO if the user is able to add a new value, it shouldn't be in the web.config. You can do that, after all is an xml file, but I'd suggest adding and retrieving it from the DB.

Comment: You shouldn't ever edit the web.config during runtime. It will cause the website to recompile.

Comment: I know it's xml and that is not a strong point in my knowledge. unfortunately whether it's a good or bad thing to do seems to be irrelevent as I've been explicitly asked to perform this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible duplicate: [Handling configuration settings in asp.net web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605001/handling-configuration-settings-in-asp-net-web-application)

Depends on what you want to do. You could either use the ConfigurationManager to get some custom configuration sections and maybe update them. But like the previous writers are saying. It is not recommended.

Otherwise you can use the application settings.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186181(v=VS.85).aspx

Better link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx

Comment: thank you, unfortunately it's a "task/assignment" that I have to do. So unless it's a trick question of some sort, there must be a way to do what I asked.

Comment: Look here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx